# How to post a JSON message to an "Https" end point URL using libcurl in C

Tags: c, https, libcurl

Is there any extra Curl-setopt to be added to handle the issue of getting error code **35 - SSL CONNECT ERROR** or any feasible method or idea or code to handle this ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

An [error code](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) of 35 means a problem in the SSL/TLS handshake.  Things to check, in order:

1. Make sure you have a current SSL certificate;

   Make sure you have read access to the SSL certificate;

   Make sure that SSL certificate has been registered with the target site;

   Make sure `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` contains the correct path to the SSL certificate;

   Make sure `CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD` contains the correct password for the certificate's private key;

   If `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` is set to `2L` (which is the default), make sure the name of the endpoint to which are you connecting matches what is specified in the SSL certificate;

For debugging, make sure `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` is set to `1L` and that you've created an error buffer and set `CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER` to point to it:

```
char curl_err_buffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE] = {0};
...
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, curl_err_buffer );
```